# 3D Display of program's output using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, glut

I am working on visualizing the output of a CUDA program I wrote by using OpenGL/GLEW/FreeGlut. I currently have a program that calculates some 3D Cartesian coordinates from some data. I also wrote a separate little OpenGL program that can display X,Y,Z points as spheres on a 3D axis.

My problem is I cannot get the OpenGL display to accept input from the two threads performing the computations.

I tried adding my OpenGL display just before I launch threads that perform the X,Y,Z calculations and having the threads write their outputs to global variables used by both sides of the program. I think that the issue with this is that the glutMainLoop() function is not returning control back over to the main program as I am left with just the empty display of the 3D axis and no points. Is there a way to launch the OpenGL display function and have it passively wait for coordinates?

Below is the display function I am working with. I am trying to have it read from global variables float XYZ_Size[] and NumObj that are updated in different parts the program. I am having the issue that when this display function is reached in the program, the program is stuck in this function.

```
///////////////////////////////main.cpp
#include "simpleGL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void gen_XYZ_coords(int time)
{
    //Large program that just munches on data creating XYZ coords
    //memset( XYZ_Size,0,sizeof(float)*(NumObj+1)*4);

    float x = 0.0;
    float y = 0.0;
    float z = 0.0;
    float sz = 1;

    NumObj = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        x = float(time)/100.0f;
        y = float(time)/100.0f;
        z = float(time)/100.0f;

        XYZ_Size[NumObj*4] = x;
        XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+1] = y;
        XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+2] = z;
        XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+3] = sz;
    }

    for(int num =0; num < NumObj; num++)
    {
        printf("x: %f y: %f z: %f size: %f\n", XYZ_Size[NumObj*4] , XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+1], XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+2], XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+3] );
    }
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float t = 0.0;
    simpleGL(argc, argv); //Gets stuck here, but I want it to be up and generating spheres when gen_xyz starts running

    for(t = 0; t < 10000; t++)
    {
        gen_XYZ_coords(t/10);
    }
}

////////////////////////simpleGL.h

#ifndef SIMPLEGL_H
#define HEADERFILE_H

extern float XYZ_Size[];
extern int NumObj;

int simpleGL(int argc, char **argv);

#endif

//////////////////////////////////simpleGL.cu

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "simpleGL.h"

GLfloat Color_Material_AMB[] = {0.25, 0.20725, 0.20725,1}; //
GLfloat Color_Material_SPEC[] = {0.296648, 0.296648, 0.296648};  //
GLfloat Color_Material_DIFF[] = {0.829, 0.829,1.0, 1.0}; //
GLfloat SpecularLight[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};//
GLfloat AmbientLight[] =  {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};//
GLfloat DiffuseLight[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0}; //
GLfloat mShininess[] = {11.264}; //set the shininess of the material 0 =very shiny 128 = duller than a rock
GLfloat Light_Position[] = {10,10,10,1};

// This is for 
float XYZ_Size[4*50]; //imit to 50 obj
int NumObj = 0;

// List for fast creationg of axis
static GLuint axes_list;

// mouse controls
int mouse_old_x, mouse_old_y;
int mouse_buttons = 0;
float rotate_x = 0.0;
float rotate_y = 0.0;
float xshift = 0.0;
float yshift = 0.0;
float translate_z = -3.0;
GLfloat angle = 0.0;

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);
void motion(int x, int y);

void init (void) 
{
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHT0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading
}

void light (void) 
{
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, SpecularLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, AmbientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, DiffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, Light_Position);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// draw a grid on the xz plane
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void drawGrid(float size, float step)
{
    // disable lighting
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glColor3f(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    for(float i=step; i <= size; i+= step)
    {
        glVertex3f(0, 0,  i);   // lines parallel to X-axis
        glVertex3f( size, 0,  i);

        glVertex3f( i, 0, 0);   // lines parallel to Z-axis
        glVertex3f( i, 0,  size);
    }

    // x-axis red
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f( size, 0, 0);

    // z-axis blue
    glColor3f(0,0,0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0,  size);

    // y-axis green
    glColor3f(0,0.5f,0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 6.4, 0); 
    glEnd();

    // enable lighting back
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// draw the local axis of an object
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void drawAxis(float size)
{
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glPushMatrix();             

    // draw axis
    glLineWidth(3);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); //red
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(size, 0, 0); //
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0); //green
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, size, 0);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1); //blue
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, size);
    glEnd();
    glLineWidth(1);

    // draw arrows(actually big square dots)
    glPointSize(5);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(size, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, size, 0);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, size);
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1);

    // restore default settings
    glPopMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Mouse event handlers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    //mouse buttons
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouse_buttons |= 1<<button;
    }
    else if (state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        mouse_buttons = 0;
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{   //mouse motion
    float dx, dy;
    dx = (float)(x - mouse_old_x);
    dy = (float)(y - mouse_old_y);

    if (mouse_buttons & 1)
    {
        rotate_x += dy * 0.2f;
        rotate_y += dx * 0.2f;
    }
    else if (mouse_buttons & 4)
    {
        int mod = glutGetModifiers();
        if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL)
        {
            xshift = xshift + dx*0.04;
            yshift = yshift - dy*0.04;
        }
        else
        {
            translate_z += dy * 0.1f;
        }
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Display Tracked Points
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void trackedSphere(float x, float y, float z, int size)
{
    //Plot sphere, preserving original coords
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef((GLfloat) x,(GLfloat) y, (GLfloat) z); //Move to object location
    glutSolidSphere(0.15,50,50); //maybe switch to size of object, scaled appropriately
    glPopMatrix();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Render Display
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void display (void) 
{
    glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity(); 

    // Draw axes 
    glPushMatrix();
    glCallList(axes_list);
    glPopMatrix();
    light();

    // shift model, use right click and drag to move Z, control+right click and drag to pan
    glTranslatef(0 + xshift,-3 + yshift,-20 + translate_z);

    // rotate based off left click and drag
    glRotatef(rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    // draw grid
    drawGrid(7.1, 0.71);

    // Display objects in buffer

    // Color objects to be drawn
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, Color_Material_DIFF);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, Color_Material_SPEC);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, Color_Material_AMB);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mShininess);

     //This needs to be an input to display as well as XYZsize
    for(int i = 0; i<NumObj; i++ )
    {
        float xl = XYZ_Size[4*(i+1)];
        float yl = XYZ_Size[4*(i+1)+1];
        float zl = XYZ_Size[4*(i+1)+2];
        float sz = XYZ_Size[4*(i+1)+3];

        trackedSphere(xl,yl,zl,sz);
    }

    drawAxis(1); // plot axis

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Window reshaping
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void reshape (int w, int h) 
{
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    //glOrtho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);  //ridged model, no perspective (objects dont get smaller in the background
    gluPerspective (60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 100.0); //Has persepective when displayed << I like this one
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int simpleGL(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("OutPutDisplay");
    init ();
    glutDisplayFunc (display);
    glutIdleFunc (display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    glutReshapeFunc (reshape);

    glutMainLoop ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi David, welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to have tried many things already. But unless you share your code, this question will soon be closed (either as "does not include a sample of the non-working code" or as "too broad").

Comment: Sorry about that, My code is very large but I will do what I can to make it more clear.

Comment: Is there any way you can reduce the code to just the minimum that is needed to reproduce your problem? (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions)

Comment: Sorry for really messing this up! I have something that I believe fully shows my problem posted in the code section now, there are 3 files but I tried to delineate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with for now. It shows how I was able to update the display with a separate function's output using some glut calls. The problem was with the glutMainLoop function, using a separate function that has glutPostRedisplay and glutMainloopEvent I was able to update the rendering when the coordinates were updated. The program will display a 3d Sphere moving across a 3D coord system.

```
///////////////////////////////main.cpp
#include "simpleGL.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void gen_XYZ_coords(int time){
    //Large program that just munches on data creating XYZ coords
    //memset( XYZ_Size,0,sizeof(float)*(NumObj+1)*4);



    float x = 0.0;
    float y = 0.0;
    float z = 0.0;
    float sz = 1;


        NumObj = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){

            x = float(time)/100.0f;
            y = float(time)/100.0f;
            z = float(time)/100.0f;

            XYZ_Size[NumObj*4] = x;
            XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+1] = y;
            XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+2] = z;
            XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+3] = sz;
        }


    for(int num =0; num < NumObj; num++){

        printf("x: %f y: %f z: %f size: %f\n", XYZ_Size[NumObj*4] , XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+1], XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+2], XYZ_Size[NumObj*4+3] );

    }


}


void main(int argc, char** argv){


    float t = 0.0;


    simpleGL(argc, argv); //Gets stuck here, but I want it to be up and generating spheres when gen_xyz starts running

    for(t = 0; t < 10000; t++){

    gen_XYZ_coords(t/10);

    updateGL();

    }



}

    ////////////////////////simpleGL.h


#ifndef SIMPLEGL_H
#define HEADERFILE_H


extern float XYZ_Size[];
extern int NumObj;

int simpleGL(int argc, char **argv);
void updateGL(void);

#endif

    //////////////////////////////////simpleGL.cu

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "simpleGL.h"



GLfloat Color_Material_AMB[] = {0.25, 0.20725, 0.20725,1}; //
GLfloat Color_Material_SPEC[] = {0.296648, 0.296648, 0.296648};  //
GLfloat Color_Material_DIFF[] = {0.829, 0.829,1.0, 1.0}; //
GLfloat SpecularLight[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};//
GLfloat AmbientLight[] =  {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};//
GLfloat DiffuseLight[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0}; //
GLfloat mShininess[] = {11.264}; //set the shininess of the material 0 =very shiny 128 = duller than a rock
GLfloat Light_Position[] = {10,10,10,1};

// This is for 
float XYZ_Size[4*50]; //imit to 50 obj
int NumObj = 0;

// List for fast creationg of axis
static GLuint axes_list;

// mouse controls
int mouse_old_x, mouse_old_y;
int mouse_buttons = 0;
float rotate_x = 0.0;
float rotate_y = 0.0;
float xshift = 0.0;
float yshift = 0.0;
float translate_z = -3.0;
GLfloat angle = 0.0;

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);
void motion(int x, int y);


void init (void) {
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHT0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading
}

void light (void) {
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, SpecularLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, AmbientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, DiffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, Light_Position);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// draw a grid on the xz plane
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void drawGrid(float size, float step)
{
    // disable lighting
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glColor3f(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    for(float i=step; i <= size; i+= step)
    {
        glVertex3f(0, 0,  i);   // lines parallel to X-axis
        glVertex3f( size, 0,  i);

        glVertex3f( i, 0, 0);   // lines parallel to Z-axis
        glVertex3f( i, 0,  size);

    }

    // x-axis red
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f( size, 0, 0);

    // z-axis blue
    glColor3f(0,0,0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0,  size);

    // y-axis green
    glColor3f(0,0.5f,0);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, 6.4, 0); 
    glEnd();

    // enable lighting back
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// draw the local axis of an object
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void drawAxis(float size)
{

    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glPushMatrix();             

    // draw axis
    glLineWidth(3);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0); //red
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(size, 0, 0); //
        glColor3f(0, 1, 0); //green
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(0, size, 0);
        glColor3f(0, 0, 1); //blue
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, size);
    glEnd();
    glLineWidth(1);

    // draw arrows(actually big square dots)
    glPointSize(5);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(size, 0, 0);
        glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
        glVertex3f(0, size, 0);
        glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, size);
    glEnd();
    glPointSize(1);

    // restore default settings
    glPopMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Mouse event handlers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y){
    //mouse buttons
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouse_buttons |= 1<<button;
    }
    else if (state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        mouse_buttons = 0;
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{   //mouse motion
    float dx, dy;
    dx = (float)(x - mouse_old_x);
    dy = (float)(y - mouse_old_y);

    if (mouse_buttons & 1)
    {
        rotate_x += dy * 0.2f;
        rotate_y += dx * 0.2f;
    }
    else if (mouse_buttons & 4)
    {
        int mod = glutGetModifiers();
        if (mod == GLUT_ACTIVE_CTRL){
            xshift = xshift + dx*0.04;
            yshift = yshift - dy*0.04;

    }
    else{
        translate_z += dy * 0.1f;
    }
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Display Tracked Points
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void trackedSphere(float x, float y, float z, int size){


    //Plot sphere, preserving original coords
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef((GLfloat) x,(GLfloat) y, (GLfloat) z); //Move to object location
        glutSolidSphere(0.15,50,50); //maybe switch to size of object, scaled appropriately
    glPopMatrix();

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Render Display
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void display (void) {

    glClearColor (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity(); 

    // Draw axes 
    glPushMatrix();
    glCallList(axes_list);
    glPopMatrix();
    light();

    // shift model, use right click and drag to move Z, control+right click and drag to pan
    glTranslatef(0 + xshift,-3 + yshift,-20 + translate_z);

    // rotate based off left click and drag
    glRotatef(rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    // draw grid
    drawGrid(7.1, 0.71);

    // Display objects in buffer

    // Color objects to be drawn
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, Color_Material_DIFF);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, Color_Material_SPEC);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, Color_Material_AMB);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mShininess);

     //This needs to be an input to display as well as XYZsize
    for(int i = 0; i<NumObj; i++ ){
        float xl = XYZ_Size[4*(i+1)];
        float yl = XYZ_Size[4*(i+1)+1];
        float zl = XYZ_Size[4*(i+1)+2];
        float sz = XYZ_Size[4*(i+1)+3];

        trackedSphere(xl,yl,zl,sz);
    }

    drawAxis(1); // plot axis

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Window reshaping
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void reshape (int w, int h) {
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    //glOrtho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);  //ridged model, no perspective (objects dont get smaller in the background
    gluPerspective (60, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 100.0); //Has persepective when displayed << I like this one
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
}




int simpleGL(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("OutPutDisplay");
    init ();
    glutDisplayFunc (display);
    glutIdleFunc (display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    glutReshapeFunc (reshape);

    return 0;
}

void updateGL(void){

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutMainLoopEvent();

}
```

Comment: Try to use a more recent OpenGL framework if you can. Glut is not really looked after anymore. GLFW is an alternative.